# How do we change the formatter extension on Visual Studio Code if there are multiple ones?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, autoformatting

Suppose we have a default code formatter on Visual Studio Code, and we install Prettier and a couple to formatter extensions to try out.

VSC would ask us which one we would like to use, but after that

1. how to we invoke a different one and
2. how do we change the default to a particular one?

Answer (score 0):

As per VSCode official doc,

> By default, the Extensions view will show the extensions you currently
> have enabled...

You can switch to a different code formatter by disabling(using the small gear icon for that specific extension) and by enabling the one of your choice.

Comment: we have to constantly enable or disable?  For example, if one extension is good for formatting Ruby but not good for formatting JavaScript, then we have to constantly enable it for Ruby and then when it is JavaScript, disable it? There should be an easier way to choose which one to use